# PHP Loop with JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, loops

I am wanting to run a jquery.append function on some divs.  Basically, I am calling information to the database, and the database knows which DIV id the content belongs to, so I want the DIV id in the .append function to be different for each value.

I guess I want to know how I can run a loop on the Jquery portion.  Everything else I am doing is working great!

Comment: Could you clarify your question with an example?

Comment: It may be easier do do the loop in PHP and output a JQuery.append line for each record.

Comment: check out jQuery.each(), probably all you need... and hey, what's wrong with an oldskool for loop?

Comment: haha, nothing wrong with the oldskool, but everything is cool with new school lol.  And I was thinking an .each would work, but I'm still learning how to use Jquery, and wasn't sure how to work it with PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say your each id is stored into an array in PHP, i.e.

```
<?php
$all_ids = Array(
  '1' => 'ID 1 value',
  '2' => 'ID 2 value',
  '3' => 'ID 3 value'
);
?>
```

You can use json_encode to translate the array to a javascript object.

```
<script>
var iterateMe = <?=json_encode($all_ids)?>;
$.each(iterateMe,function(index, value) {
  // This is where you would run each append
  alert(index + ": " + value);
});
</script>
```

Then, iterate as normal!

Comment: this looks good, now I just need to learn arrays in PHP. lol.  I am learning and that's all that matters.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: I am very confused, I am wanting to do a PHP loops through an unknown amount of values from the database.  I can use an array, but idk how to loop it for the jquery.  Basically I want the #divid on the .append function to change with each pass of the loop.

Comment: Well let's break this down. Hopefully you're (1) Using $myArray = mysql_fetch_array() to get an array from the database. You should use <pre><?=var_dump($myArray)?></pre> to understand how that array works. Then (2) You should be converting that to JavaScript Object Notation via PHP's json_encode($myArray) method as seen above. If you've never worked with JSON before, don't fret. Check out this 3 minute tutorial: http://secretgeek.net/json_3mins.asp and compare it with your PHP array. Lastly, (3) to help better grasp the "changing #divid", try console.log(whatever var you stored json in).

Comment: If that doesn't help at all, you'll need to send code, because all the concepts you've talked about have been spread thin by now. :)